# Import Contacts from .vcf file (NO google. Ever)

Tags: contacts

I've looked around... (stack exchange) and no former Q? seems to apply.

I would like to import the contacts so that the NUMBER (and email, if it exists) is listed beneath the contacts name? Instead of a jumbled mess?

The problem could be related to a difference between how android v4.4.2 (old phone, where the .vcf file was generated) and v4.1.2 (new phone) handle contacts. The (stock) app behaves differently.

I do *NOT* use google for anything, for security reasons. Instead, I use Fdroid apps or apps I've downloaded to PC then transferred and then side loaded. In other words, there is NO google account in my phone (ever)

My Old Phone got stolen, but fortunately I'd backed up the contacts from the phone using

[Frdoid, Export Contacts][1][1]: https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=contacts&fdid=am.ed.exportcontacts

These save to "contacts.vcf" in a directory of your choosing, I exported mine and saved externally on PC hard drive.

Trouble is, using

[Import Contacts, Fdroid][2][2]: https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=contacts&fdid=am.ed.importcontacts

The import does happen, however the contacts are scrambled. There is a contact for each NUMBER, and a contact for each NAME, but these have become disconnected.

I've checked the *.vcf file, which appears to be a variant of a comma or semicolon delimited *.cvs file... I can't figure out what's going wrong.